# Making Carousel which displays part of next/prev responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel which displays parts of the next and prev images but at the moment it is not responsive for anything above mobile size. Here is the code:

```
<style>
        .item img:first-child,
        .item img:last-child {
            display: none;
        }
        /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .item img {
                float: left;
                /*width: 600px;*/
            }
            .item img:first-child,
            .item img:last-child {
                display: block;
            }
            .item.active {
                overflow: hidden;
                margin: 0 -546px;
            }
        }
        /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            .item img {
                /*width: 600px;*/
            }
            .item.active {
                margin: 0 -434px;
            }
        }
        /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
        @media (min-width: 1200px) {
            .item img {
                /*width: 600px;*/
            }
            .item.active {
                margin: 0 -427px;
            }
        }

        .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -33%; }
        .carousel-inner .next        { left:  33%; }
        .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -33%; }

    </style>

<div class="container-fluid no-pad">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 no-pad">
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div align="center" class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1148x780" alt="Chania" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Left and right controls -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want the carousel to shrink (which is why I added img-responsive BS class). But at the moment it is staying the same size

Comment: Your code is formally wrong. The ".carousel-inner" three lines are out of style declaration, and the link after the comment "left and right controls" is not closed with ">". Try to correct the errors first.

Comment: It is Friday! Anyway changed that now

Comment: You still here Baro?!

Comment: To be honest I don't know well what is the result you are looking for. Your carousel have 3 image for slide, and I don't know what are the result for various "width" media query. This is your code in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/muyenfL1/1/ and seems to be correct, try to resize the box of result.

Comment: I just want the carousel to scale down with screen size displaying all 3 images side-by-side until mobile where only 1 is displayed at a time. Currently the mobile version works but the other sizes are putting images on different lines?

Answer (score 1):

I hope is this what you are looking for, I have simplified your CSS:

```
.item img {
  float:left;
  max-width:33.33% !important;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

  .item img {
    max-width:100% !important;  
   }

  .item img:first-child,
  .item img:last-child {
    display: none !important;
  }

}


.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -33%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  33%; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left: -33%; }
```

[Check the JSFiddle result here.](https://jsfiddle.net/muyenfL1/3/)

Comment: Kind of although only half of the first and third image should be visible?

Comment: If this is your final goal, you start from the wrong question. If I understand you want to see for each slide the half of first image, the full image centered as second, and the half of third image, right ? If is correct, you must use absolute position, but in this context all the layout must be change and perhaps it is not possible because the plugin create own rules and styles, and overwrite there is not simple.

Comment: I have achieved this for a certain screen size though. It is only when I change the window size that it gets messed up?